# Private gem server - dependencies not being found on server (404)

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2, rubygems, bundler

The [RubyGems site](http://guides.rubygems.org/run-your-own-gem-server/) makes it sound pretty easy to run a private gem server!

My test setup is like this: one AWS EC2 instance is my workstation, and I've got another set up to be the gem server.

On the gem server instance I've installed the `pry` gem. If I run `gem server` on that instance and visit the public DNS in my web browser I can see `pry` and all the dependencies in the list of gems.

On my workstation I've created a fake app directory with a simple Gemfile:

```
source "http://ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8808"

gem "pry"
```

Seems simple enough! But when I run `bundle install` on the workstation I get the following error:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-20-246 my_app]$ bundle
Fetching source index from http://ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8808/
Resolving dependencies...

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: bad response Not Found  404 (http://ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8808/gems/coderay-1.1.1.gem)

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: bad response Not Found  404 (http://ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8808/gems/method_source-0.8.2.gem)

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: bad response Not Found  404 (http://ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8808/gems/slop-3.6.0.gem)
Using bundler 1.12.5
An error occurred while installing coderay (1.1.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install coderay -v '1.1.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

So it seems to recognize `pry` is available but the dependencies, starting with `coderay`, aren't found (404 error).

I've fiddled with the `--dir` flag when running `gem server` so that it looks like this:

`gem server --dir=/home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.0 --dir=/usr/share/ruby/gems/2.0 --dir=/home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.0/cache/`

...and I've even gone into these directories and run `gem generate_index` as I saw recommended on another question but I'm still unable to install `pry` on my workstation using this private server as the `source`.

Is there something I'm missing??

Answer (score 0):

Almost every gem depends on other gems. When you want to install gems from a private gem server only and you do not allow to use the default server at `https://rubygems.org` as a fallback, then you have to make sure that all others gems in the correct versions are available on your private gem server too.

You can check [the `pry` page on rubygems](https://rubygems.org/gems/pry) to see its dependencies. Currently `pry ('0.10.3')` depends on:

- `coderay ('~> 1.0.0')`
- `method_source ('~> 0.8.1')`
- `slot ('~> 3.4')`

Make this dependency available on your private gem server too to remove the  `Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: bad response Not Found  404` errors for that gems.

In a next step you would need to dig deeper and make all gems available these three gems depend on: `coderay` doesn't have external dependencies, but `method_source` has some, install them too. Continue until there are no more gems missing that are in the dependency tree.

Comment: Yes I realize that all of the dependencies would need to be on my gem server as well. Obviously `coderay` and the other immediate dependencies of `pry` are on my server; otherwise `pry` wouldn't be installed. So the question is: why isn't `coderay` being found?